# Where should I report risque profile images

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

Not to sound prudish but I noticed [this profile image](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3862535/kabir-roy) which, in my view, is unbecoming of a professional forum. So two questions:

- Where would I report such an issue
- Would you agree that image is pushing the limit?

Comment: The general consensus is that profile images enjoy a lot of leeway. The one you link to is firmly within that, IMO

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164109/can-moderators-ban-flag-inappropriate-profile-pictures

Comment: In truly NSFW cases, Gravatars *do* get removed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127861/is-my-profile-picture-really-offensive-enough-to-block (but as said I don't think this one should be)

Comment: Not sure how strict the the standards for avatars are, but I __custom flagged__ one user whose image was flipping people the bird. That flag was marked helpful after a few days and the avatar was reverted to a default gravatar. Just be specific in the custom flag. Link to this meta post if desired.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not say it was bothering me. I even said I didn't want to sound prudish. I merely asked the question where do you report risque images and did the one I linked to push that limit. My opinion of the image never enters the equation.

Comment: Perhaps you want to read what you wrote again. You clearly state that in your view that image "is unbecoming of a professional forum"

Comment: ... and it arguably *is* somewhat unbecoming of a professional forum. We're just very liberal about it in regards to gravatars and that's that. I don't see why it's necessary to attack the OP and accuse him of "bigotry"

Comment: FFS there are PHP, SQL and JavaScript rooms, so I'm not gonna be offended by some image.

Comment: So, two people laughing who happen to be showing some non-offensive skin is less "professional" than ninjas, octopi, ponies, unicorns or other mythical creatures? I think this is about as innocuous of a "rique" picture as you can get.

Comment: This is  the first time I've ever asked a question on Meta. Lesson learned and won't do it again. I didn't expect reddit-like responses.

Comment: @Rob I think you should be learning a different lesson. Some of your meta-related comments in some questions are just unnecessary at best.

Comment: @Joshua How is your response to a six-year old thread significant to the world at large or anything dealing with life at all? Yours is another example of a reddit-like dung heap response.

Answer (score 6):

If you believe that a user's profile picture is inappropriate, then flag one of the user's posts (the user profile is not directly flaggable) with the option *"in need of moderator intervention"*, and explain to the moderator why you believe that the picture is NSFW.

[image]

The moderators [have the ability to change a user's profile picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164109/can-moderators-ban-flag-inappropriate-profile-pictures).